# Getting undefined from Meteor.call on client, but on server variable contains data

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I've got a function on server like this

```
Meteor.methods({
"functionName": function(data) {
//calculations, http requests etc.

console.log(variable); //shows variable properly
return variable;
}
});
```

When I do `console.log(variable)` on server I can see data.

Now I do `Meteor.call` on client:

```
Meteor.call('functionName', data, function(err, res) {
console.log(res); //shows undefined
});
```

What's wrong here? Why can't I use response variable on client?

EDIT:

I've been struggling with this for couple of hours and I narrowed down errors to one, `HTTP.get()` function. Now it looks like this:

```
//some calculations
var variable = HTTP.get('url');
return variable.data; //should return an object
```

I tried to wrap it with Promise but then it didn't work. It looked like this:

```
//some calculations
function promise() {
  var variable = HTTP.get('url');
  resolve('Done.');
}

promise().then(function() {
  console.log(variable); //doesn't even work on server this way
  return variable;
});
```

Comment: Perhaps the variable is not serializable. Please provide more details about it and check `err` as well.

Comment: Error returns nothing. Can you elaborate on "not serializable"? I'm not familiar with this term. Variable set is a string, if it changes anything.

Comment: And are you sure that value is indeed returned from the method synchronously? If it is within an asynchronous callback, you will need to use a promise or wrap the async call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `http requests` are issue here, try to return a Promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and your question, my guess is that your return statement is happening within an async callback of an HTTP request.  You can use [Meteor.wrapAsync](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make these requests synchronous and get a valid return statement.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring due to synchronous call of http.
What really happen here you function is not waiting for http call response.
You should use Meteor.wrapAsync;